# Scala: How can I explicitly compare two Options?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-option

If I have two Options such as

```
val a = Option(2)
val b = Option(1)
```

I can write

```
List(a,b).sorted
```

and it sorts correctly by inserting an implicit Ordering. How can I get a reference to this Ordering so I can call `compare(a,b)` and get the result? I'd like the equivalent of

```
val comparison = a.compare(b)
```

except without having a and b be instances of Ordered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just ask for the ordering implicit directly:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> implicitly[Ordering[Option[Int]]]
res0: Ordering[Option[Int]] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$3@501a9177

scala> res0.compare(Some(1), Some(3))
res1: Int = -1
```

Comment: Works, but there is no need to ask for the ordering implicit.  `Ordering[Option[Int]].compare(a, b)` works as well.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to manipulate Options is using `for` expressions.

```
for (a1 <- a; b1 <- b) yield a1.compare(b1)  // Some(-1)
```

If at least one of the numbers is `None`, the result is `None`.

```
val x: Option[Int] = None
for (a1 <- a; b1 <- x) yield a1.compare(b1)  // None
```

A compare function may be defined as

```
def compare(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]) = {
  for (a1 <- a; b1 <- b) yield a1.compare(b1)
}.get
```

**Updated:**

If you want the Nones you can use pattern matching:

```
def compare(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]) = (a, b) match {
  case (Some(a), Some(b)) => a.compare(b)
  case (None, None)       => 0
  case (None, _)          => -1  // None comes before
  case (_, None)          => 1
}

val list: List[Option[Int]] = List(List(Some(1), None, Some(4), Some(2), None))
val list2 = list.sortWith(compare(_, _) < 0)    
//  list2 = List(None, None, Some(1), Some(2), Some(4))
```

Comment: This is an interesting idiom. For my use case I actually want Nones to be ordered as well, either first or last, so I can't use it here but it looks handy for other situations.

Comment: Careful! The first compare function sample throws an NoSuchElementException if a or b (or both) is None.